# Multiple ArrayFormula in the same formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Can ArrayForumla be used multiple times in a single formula?

`=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX('Form Responses 2'!A2:AN2,ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(COLUMN('Form Responses 2'!K2:AN2)*(--('Form Responses 2'!K2:AN2<>""))))))`

I want the formula after ArrayFormula to be applied to all new rows when data is added or captured.

Currently, when I have tried, it's not giving me any output or error.

Comment: Without seeing your spreadsheet and data, it's not possible for us to know what the intent of such a formula is. However, I can tell you that A.) one instance of `ArrayFormula` wrapping an entire formula will apply to any applicable portions of that formula without a need to repeat it; and B.) there are many functions that do not work with `ArrayFormula` (`MAX` among them) in the sense of returning multiple `MAX` values. The latter is because `MAX` itself is an array formula already (i.e., it must process multiple pieces of data to arrive at its result).

Comment: Perhaps if you share a link to your spreadsheet (or to a copy of it), a volunteer contributor here will be able to suggest an alternative approach. But there isn't much we can tell you sight unseen.

Answer (score 1):

So I later found the solution i.e.,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(J2:J), VLOOKUP(J2:J,QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN('Form Responses 2'!K1:AN1&"_"&'Form Responses 2'!K2:AN),"_"), "Where Col2 <>''", 0), 2, 0),))
```

[Working Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c4ofR06UETzGakbUJc-5N7Q-NXFMegs3FYQtTTBUfgk/edit?usp=sharing)

We can have multiple array formulas, but we can't have nested arrays. Having several ARRAYFORMULA is the same as just doing one ARRAYFORMULA on the top level.

That being said, INDEX function in Google Sheets doesn't handle arrays. It does in Excel. In this case, MAX shouldn't return an array so it wouldn't matter.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).